# c++ taking input in float and converting into string

Tags: c++

I want to take float input from user with only two decimal point(999.99) and convert it into string

```
float amount;
cout << "Please enter the amount:";
cin.ignore();
cin >> amount;
string Price = std::to_string(amount);
```

my output for this code is 999.989990

Comment: Just omit `cin.ignore();`, it's completely unclear, why you want it to use here. Also you note not all exact decimals can be represented by a `float` or `double` value.

Comment: Let's see how you output the number.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Probably something like `std::cout << Price << std::endl;`

Answer (score 4):

`to_string` doesn't let you specify how many decimal places to format. I/O streams do:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << amount;
std::string Price = ss.str();
```

If you need to represent the decimal value exactly, then you can't use a binary `float` type. Perhaps you might multiply by 100, representing prices as an exact integer number of pennies.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to round the number to two decimal digits, you could try:

```
amount = roundf(amount * 100) / 100;
```

And then convert it into `std::string`.